# Issues with making Cocoa app AppleScript-scriptable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, cocoa-scripting

I want to make my app scriptable and am running into a few issues I hope some of you may help me with since my experience with making apps scriptable is not great.

The app is *not* document-based and has a several global named objects of the same class that I want to be accessed from AppleScript. For example, say that I want to have a several catalogues, each named, say "animals", "plants", "cars". I have managed to add several properties to the application class (in AppleScript), each representing one of the catalogues:

```
<class name="application" description="My application." code="capp" inherits="application">
  <cocoa class="NSApplication"/>
  <property name="animals catalogue" code="acat" description="…" type="catalogue" access="r">
    <cocoa key="animalsCatalogue"/>
  </property>
  <property name="cars catalogue" code="ccat" description="…" type="catalogue" access="r">
    <cocoa key="carsCatalogue"/>
  </property>
  <property name="plants catalogue" code="pcat" description="…" type="catalogue" access="r">
    <cocoa key="plantsCatalogue"/>
  </property>
</class>
```

I am able to **successfully** fetch any of those variables, e.g.

```
tell application "MyApp"
  set c to get animals catalogue
end tell
```

gets me really the catalogue variable (`«class ����» "Animals" of application "MyApp"`).

Unfortunately, where it gets tricky is when it comes to getting a property from the catalogue - for example 'empty'. Here is the catalogue definition:

```
<class name="catalogue" code="ctlg" description="...">
    <cocoa class="XYCatalogue"/>
    <property name="empty" code="empt" description="Is the catalogue empty?" type="boolean" access="r">
        <cocoa key="isEmpty"/>
    </property>
</class>
```

The issue here is that when running this AppleScript:

```
tell application "MyApp"
  set c to get animals catalogue
  get empty of c
end tell
```

results in an error: `MyApp got an error: Can’t make «class ����» "Animals" into type specifier.`

Implementation-wise, I have the NSApplication subclassed (and yes, I have specified the main class in Info.plist), which implements several methods, returning those particular catalogues. The `XYCatalogue` class implements the `-objectSpecifier` method this way:

```
return [[[NSNameSpecifier alloc] initWithContainerClassDescription:
                  [NSScriptClassDescription classDescriptionForClass:[NSApp class]]
                               containerSpecifier:nil 
                               key:@"allCatalogues" 
                               name:[self name]] autorelease];
```

The NSApplication subclass implements a `-allCatalogues` method that returns all the catalogues. I have tried even using the `NSUniqueIDSpecifier` and the `NSPropertySpecifier`, all in vain. And yes, the NSApplication subclass does implement both `-valueWithName:inPropertyWithKey:` and `-valueInAllCataloguesWithName:` methods and neither is invoked (have breakpoints in both of them).

I have sincerely read Apple's guide several times, however, still can't figure out where is the issue and I'm hanging on this for a few days now. I would be most thankful for any nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Just some info: there's a sample code project called "SimpleScripting" which is included with Xcode-

Comment: @DigiMonk: I have gone through all the ``SimpleScripting*`` sample projects - SimpleScripting only adds a BOOL property to the app, which works fine as it does not reference other objects. There are other sample projects as well, including the Sketch project, where, however, everything is document-based. I'm basing my code on SimpleScriptingObjects now, which however uses ``element`` types on the application to get the objects, which is unfortunately not an option for me as I need to be able to easily specify each catalogue directly without listing all catalogues...

Comment: As a general point, getting object specifiers with “«class»” in them (no identifier, no four byte code) means there’s something messed up in your `-objectSpecifier` method.  Specifically, and this is just a guess, did you make your own NSApplication subclass?  If so, try changing `[NSApp class]` to `[NSApplication class]`.  It’s not exactly correct, but may work better.

Comment: Chris N: This is an interesting note about NSApplication subclass - it might have been the issue. I've quite followed the sample app when returning the objectSpecifier, I guess it really is the issue with the NSApp vs. NSApplication... Dumb me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're not seeing the proper class name such as *animals catalogue* but instead see the `«class»` code is a good indicator that your `-objectSpecifier` function returns the wrong specifier.

There is an important rule that one need to follow with `-objectSpecifier`:

The key passed to `-initWithContainerClassDescription:` needs to be the same as the one that's entered for the property definition for that class under `<cocoa key>`. In your example, they do not match, however: The property accessor is called *animalsCatalogue* but the key you use in `-objectSpecifier` is *allCatalogues*. They need to match.

Also, as the Apple docs say, the `containerSpecifier` may only be `nil` if the target is the application, but not for any other scriptable objects. The Cocoa Scripting engine won't probably report this back as an error if you pass nil for a non-application object, but the results will be similar to passing a wrong key.